# Svelte - non-trivial intermediate variable within each loop

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

How can I create variables inside Svelte's HTML like in React, or is it not at all how I am supposed to use Svelte. I know the example below is trivial but I'm thinking of a case where I really need some heavy logic for `subArray` (could not use a one liner)

**React**

```js
<ul>
  {myArray.map((item) => {
    const subArray = item.items.filter(i = i > 0) // <- how can I have an intermediate variable like this in Svelte?
    return <li>{subArray.map(...)}</li>
  }}
</ul>
```

**Svelte**

```html
<ul>
  {#each myArray as item}
    <li>
        {#each <complex-logic> as subItem}
        ...
        {/each}
    </li>
  {/each}
</ul>
```

Comment: I think the Svelte way would be to create `array of subArray` (possibly reactively with `$:`) in `<script></script>` and do `{#each array as subArray}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`{@const}`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-const) directive, which is a recent addition to Svelte. In your use case:

```js
<ul>
  {#each myArray as item}
    {@const subArray = item.items.filter(i => i > 0)}
    <li>
        {#each subArray as subItem}
        ...
        {/each}
    </li>
  {/each}
</ul>
```

Comment: I thought so too, but this gives an error? Have a look at my answer...

Comment: @Corrl see my comment to your answer ;)

Answer (score 7):

If it's not too complicated you can directly modify the array inside `{#each}`

```
<script>
    let myArray = [
        {id: 1, items: [-2,-1,0,1,2]},
        {id: 2, items: [-20,-10,0,10,20]},
        {id: 3, items: [-222,-111,0,111,222]},
    ]
</script>

<ul>
    {#each myArray as item}
    <li>
        {item.id}:
        {#each item.items.filter(item => item >= 0) as subItem}
        {subItem}, 
        {/each}
    </li>
    {/each}
</ul>
```

or you could use the new [`{@const}` directive](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-const)

```
<ul>
    {#each myArray as item}
    {@const filteredItems = item.items.filter(i => i > 0)} 
    <li>
        {item.id}:
        {#each filteredItems as subItem}
        {subItem}, 
        {/each}
    </li>
    {/each}
</ul>
```

And if it's even more complicated, why not extract the logic into a function

```
    function complicatedModification(arr) {
        return arr.filter(item => item > 0)
    }
</script>

...
  {#each complicatedModification(item.items) as subItem}
        {subItem}, 
  {/each}
...
```

Here's a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/cedfbd54fe8d4d1bafbf6a5493cbaff6?version=3.46.4) with all the options

Comment: The error is possibly because you reuse the `item` variable name in your lambda?

Comment: Thank you both, I hadn't header about @const. The function is likely what I'll use.